# How to pause amazon kendra index?

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-kendra

Is there a way to pause an amazon kendra index so I don't get charged, but also don't have to delete the index so I don't have to re-build it if I want to use it later again?

I don't see any official documentation supporting this feature so I'm assuming it's a no but asking around just in case!

This is the only option I found:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/delete-index.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to pause an index. Once you create it (which takes a bit of time), it is there. You can update it, list available indexes, delete it, query using it, and so on. But you cannot pause it so its like it does not exist.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought... thanks!